# Site Tagline ended up in permalink

Tags: permalinks, theme-customizer

When I added a custom tagline for my site in Customizer it made  that tagline part of the permalink without my realizing it. I have turned off the tagline. It does not appear in the permalink settings panel. It is too long to leave there. Do I have to remove it manually from each page?

Comment: This is definitely not the normal behaviour of WordPress. Are you certain it was the tagline that you were editing? What did your permalinks look like before and after adding the tagline?

Comment: I wasn't paying any attention to the permalinks in the beginning since I wasn't sure what I wanted them to be so I don't know when it showed up. But it is a unique five-word phrase that, as far as I can remember I only ever put in the Site Identity tagline box in Customizer. Here is a sample: http://wp6.temp.domains/~brakeley/giving-flight-to-great-ideas/history/

As I mentioned it does not appear in the permalinks in the Settings window.
At any rate I am now faced with changing the permalinks on all the pages and am wondering if there is some way to do it en masse.

Comment: OK I realized that I am overthinking this. Wordpress used the tagline as the slug for the home page and so it became part of the permalink for all the subsequent pages. I was worrying that users would have to type in the whole string to get where they wanted to go and of course they do not. I should change the home page slug to something better for SEO and leave it at that. So I guess I am saying "never mind and thankyou".

Comment: Have you made all your pages sub pages of the home page?

Comment: I thought I had but when I ended up changing the home page slug I discovered i had not. All is fixed now. Thank you for checking in.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress used the tagline as the slug for the home page and so it became part of the permalink for all the subsequent pages.

And I realized that I am overthinking this.I was worrying that users would have to type in the whole string to get where they wanted to go and of course they would not. I will change the home page slug to something more relevant for SEO and leave it at that. So I guess I am saying "never mind."